# Arrange data in bracket based on specific order in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have an array and after programming, I get the position and the value of non-zero data, which looks like (x, y, z) = (row, column, value)

```
[(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (2, 3, 2), (3, 0, 3), (3, 1, 3), (3, 3, 2)]
```

This result in order in 'the smallest number of row to the highest'.

Is there any method that I can make the result order in 'the smallest number of column to the highest' and also 'the smallest number of value to the highest'?

Thanks for any help!!

This is the code I used:

```
import numpy as np

groupMatrix = np.array([
[1, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 2],
[3, 3, 0, 2]
])
i = np.nonzero(groupMatrix)

res = np.vstack([i, groupMatrix[i]])
print(list(zip(*res)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do that,
In this case you can sort the `list` of `tuples` by `key` which is the `column`

```
import numpy as np

groupMatrix = np.array([
[1, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 2],
[3, 3, 0, 2]
])
i = np.nonzero(groupMatrix)

res = np.vstack([i, groupMatrix[i]])
arr = list(zip(*res))

col_sorted = sorted(arr, key=lambda item: item[1]) # sorted by column
val_sorted = sorted(arr, key=lambda item: item[2]) # sorted by value
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `key` argument in the builtin `sorted()` function to change the key to the ith index:

```
array = [(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (2, 3, 2), (3, 0, 3), (3, 1, 3), (3, 3, 2)]

ascending_column_order = sorted(array, key=lambda x: x[1])
```